# GIBBON::must set an api_key prior to making a call - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, gibbon

I used a tutorial to set up my app with mailchimp so that it sends a new subscriber to a mailchimp list. Everything is working just fine if you go through the flow. But when I ran Rspec Half of my test suite is red with this error `Gibbon::GibbonError:You must set an api_key prior to making a call`. I tried setting my api key where it says but it didn't work? I'll post some code for clarity.

### Gibbon.rb:

```
Gibbon::API.api_key = ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"]
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = true
```

### JOB

```
     class SubscribeUserToMailingListJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(subscriber)
    gb = Gibbon::API.new(Figaro.env.mailchimp_api_key)
    gb.lists.subscribe({:id => ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"], :email => {:email => subscriber.email}, :merge_vars => {:FNAME => subscriber.first_name, :LNAME => subscriber.last_name}, :double_optin => false})
  end
end
```

### MODEL:

```
 def subscribe_user_to_mailing_list
   SubscribeUserToMailingListJob.perform_later(self)
 end
```

### ERROR

```
 Create a subscriber Subscriber can sign in
  Failure/Error: gb.lists.subscribe({:id => ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"],   :email => {:email => subscriber.email}, :merge_vars => {:FNAME =>   subscriber.first_name, :LNAME => subscriber.last_name}, :double_optin =>   false})

Gibbon::GibbonError:
You must set an api_key prior to making a call
```

I'm lost on this one. Any help would be great! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about generating a MailChimp API-key for a start? If you have a MailChimp account you can easily get one in the extra´s menu.

Replace "MAILCHIMP_API_KEY" with your key in the line: Gibbon::API.api_key = ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"]

Answer (score 4):

OP, I am assuming that in your tests you had a `MAILCHIMP_API_KEY` env var set, and yet Gibbon was still giving you the error as if you hadn't got one at all?

The issue is that Gibbon expects any API key string to be formatted as per Mailchimp's API keys. So if in your test you're using string `api_key_123`, you can *set* that without issue using `Gibbon::API.api_key = "api_key_123"`, but at the point where you try to use it, Gibbon will act like it doesn't exist. Whereas if you use a Mailchimp-formatted key ,like `8472f063cf868ab9a49ccbb118c1d5f1-us15`, Gibbon will acknowledge its existence.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should require the gem dotenv like this in your model

```
class SubscribeUserToMailingListJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  require 'dotenv'
  Dotenv.load


  def perform(subscriber)
    gb = Gibbon::API.new(Figaro.env.mailchimp_api_key)
    gb.lists.subscribe({:id => ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"], :email => {:email => subscriber.email}, :merge_vars => {:FNAME => subscriber.first_name, :LNAME => subscriber.last_name}, :double_optin => false})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A follow up on this question. The main reason was missing env variable in test environment and even if one mocks the env variable in `before` block, it won't work as Gibbon sets the API key in the initializer. As a fix for this without using a real API key for test env, we can set a test API directly in before block of the test like

```
def before
  Gibbon::Request.api_key = 'test-us3'
end
```

Please note the "-" in the key. That's the trick which passed the validation in the gem as implemented [here](https://github.com/amro/gibbon/blob/cade20ca2438cd1b182dad70cbb77fb895779d10/lib/gibbon/api_request.rb#L184)